# angularjs - keep focus on input when clicked on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to keep the focus on the  textarea  when click on one div a button .

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myText" id = "area1" ></input>
```

And my buttons are dynamically generated by template in a directive as,

```
 <my-buttons > </my-buttons>

app.directive('myButtons', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "templates/buttons.html"
        link: function ($scope) {}
    };
});
```

Template is

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div ng-click="submitResult();">
            <div ng-style="color:red"> <span>OK</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I click on submit it removes the focus from the input but I want that the focus to remain on the input where it was. I know that we can set the focus by

```
document.getElementById("id").focus();
```

Do I have to add a attribute to the  myButtons directive and pass the id of the input or there is any other workaround in angularjs . There can be many number of such input and buttons on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no angular method to tell an element not to loose focus even when another control needs focus. You need to implement this functionality yourself by manually handling `blur` event.

Comment: Actually if you look at his template , he is using div element as button

Answer (score 1):

Following Charlie's answer, and as a suggestion to get what you want done, try keeping track of who's currently focused. On button click, return the focus to the element that was last focused.